# Add element with existing navigation property using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
 public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(CreateSampleDto createSampleDto)
 {
     Sample sample = new()
     {
         YarnName = createSampleDto.YarnName,
         LoopsQuantity = createSampleDto.LoopsQuantity,
         RowsQuantity = createSampleDto.RowsQuantity,
         NeedleSize = createSampleDto.NeedleSize,
         NeedleSizeUnit = createSampleDto.NeedleSizeUnit,
         Description = createSampleDto.Description,
         User = _userService.GetUserByIdAsync(createSampleDto.UserId)
     };

     await _databaseContext.Samples.AddAsync(sample);
     await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
     return true;
 }
```

I want to add new Sample object to database using Entity Framework. Sample has got navigation property called User (User has many Samples). I would like to use only navigation properties in my code, but I think that getting User from database with this approach can be inefficient. Is there a better way to attach User who exists in database when I create new Sample object? I tried with Attach() function, but I can't deal with it at all.

Comment: `User = new User { Id = createSampleDto.UserId }`

Comment: *Is there a better way* -- Yes, *do* set `sample.UserId`, nothing wrong with it. Other ways are needlessly verbose. IMO this issue of strong-typed Id's is greatly overrated. In my career as developer I've never mixed up Id values just because they had the same type. Even then, there's also a thing called unit/integration testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is pretty standard. Fetching the user by ID should be a relatively quick operation and it also serves to validate that the user exists, and can enforce any lower level rules. For example if you are building a multi-tenant SAAS system where various users from various tenants are in the same database, your services would have code to ensure that the data retrieved for the current logged in session is only ever relevant, I.e. for their registered Tenant ID. If your code just sets FKs then there can be a risk that an invalid FK gets assigned to a record. (I.e. a FK for a record that exists, but should not apply to this user/scenario)

If there are no potential concerns around incorrect FKs being assigned, the alternative is to attach stubs to the DbContext to represent existing records. However, especially when working with injected DbContexts and actions that might be part of a larger work chain, you should always check the DbContext tracking cache before attaching an entity. Failing to do so could result in situational exceptions where the context is already tracking a matching entity.

```
bool usedStub = false;
var user = _context.Users.Local
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == createSampleDto.UserId);
if (user == null)
{
    user = new User { UserId = createSampleDto.UserId };
    _context.Attach(user);
    usedStub = true;
}

 Sample sample = new()
 {
     YarnName = createSampleDto.YarnName,
     LoopsQuantity = createSampleDto.LoopsQuantity,
     RowsQuantity = createSampleDto.RowsQuantity,
     NeedleSize = createSampleDto.NeedleSize,
     NeedleSizeUnit = createSampleDto.NeedleSizeUnit,
     Description = createSampleDto.Description,
     User = user
 };

_context.Samples.Add(sample);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

// Remove the stub
if (usedStub)
    _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

The premise is to check the .Local tracking cache for the User, if found, we will use that. This check does not go to the database. If it isn't already tracked then we can create the stub and attach it. Since we have attached a stub which just has the UserID we don't want the DbContext returning that stub in situations where we might want to load an actual user later on in the request, so if we added a stub then we detach that stub once we are done.

Now working this into your existing UserService pattern likely won't be that trivial. This is one reason why abstracting the DbContext can be problematic, so it is probably safer to just load the user using the UserService as you are currently doing.

With the user service I'd consider something like a GetUserOrStub(id) type method with a result object for the resulting user and whether a stub was returned or not:

```
public class GetStubResponse<T> where T:class
{
    public bool IsStub { get; private set; } = false;
    public T Entity { get; private set; }

    public GetStubResponse(T entity, bool isStub) 
    { 
        Entity = entity;
        IsStub = isStub;
    } 
}
```

Then in the service:

```
public GetStubResponse<User> GetUserOrStub(int userId)
{
    var user = _databaseContext.Users.Local
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == _userId);

    if (user != null)
        return new GetStubResponse(user, false);

    user = new User { UserId = createSampleDto.UserId };
    _databaseContext.Attach(user);
    return new GetStubResponse(user, true);
}
```

Now when calling in your code:

```
public async Task<bool> CreateAsync(CreateSampleDto createSampleDto)
{
    var userResponse = _userService.GetUserOrStub(createSampleDto.UserId)

    Sample sample = new()
    {
        YarnName = createSampleDto.YarnName,
        LoopsQuantity = createSampleDto.LoopsQuantity,
        RowsQuantity = createSampleDto.RowsQuantity,
        NeedleSize = createSampleDto.NeedleSize,
        NeedleSizeUnit = createSampleDto.NeedleSizeUnit,
        Description = createSampleDto.Description,
        User = userResponse.Entity;
    };

    await _databaseContext.Samples.AddAsync(sample);
    await _databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    if (userResponse.IsStub)
        _databaseContext.Entry(userResponse.Entity).State = EntityState.Detached;

    return true;
}
```

This assumes that the _databaseContext instance is injected and shared between this service (SampleService?) and the UserService.

Comment: As I said above, so verbose... In an average model there are far more FKs. That would require lots of these `GetXOrStub` methods. I don't see the added value. It doesn't protect against non-existing records or against erroneously using a value for a wrong FK (it's possible to create a user stub having another entity's Id value), to name two common objections against setting FK properties directly. It's also more work for the change tracker.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this helping response. After all, I think I will just add int UserId FK despite having navigation property. It is just easy. I thought that using only navigation property is more 'professional' or 'modern programming', but it is not worth to write so many lines when I can do everything with int UserId. Thank you again, I appreciate the help!